# Is there a straightforward way to measure Xcode build times

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process

I am working on a **HUGE** iOS client project that takes a frustratingly long time to build. (and an **appalling amount of time to install and launch on a device, but I don't think there's much to do about that.) My development machine (mid 2012 MBP) already has had the HD upgraded to an SSD, which obviously makes a big difference vs a magnetic HD. I decided to spring for an upgrade from 8 GB to 16 GB of memory.

Now I'd like to measure the time for a full build (after clean). Is there a straightforward way to measure build time? (I guess I should have asked this before I installed the new memory so I could get build times before and after the memory upgrade...)

Comment: @AaronBrager, thanks for the link. That appears to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it worked out!